# Maven build fails from jenkins

Tags: maven, ubuntu, jenkins

I am trying to do a maven build using via a jenkins pipeline and the build fails with the error :

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBoot
```

While trying to do the same build from the backend using jenkins user the build succeeds without any error , I am doing this on ubuntu 18.04 .

Comment: Same environment variable, same maven version, same JDK version, same maven settings ?

Comment: @wargre Yes , it's the backend for the very same jenkins server .